# AWK doesn't add new column

Tags: awk

My file has 4 numeric columns. Below testing if columns are identified correctly. `tail -n +2` is to remove header.

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' | head

41261311 41261568 2798880 2799128
-115939711 -115940021 2799541 2799827
-115939159 -115939706 2800137 2800685
-115939033 -115939106 2801113 2801186
-115938419 -115938978 2801191 2801726
-115937404 -115937535 2812511 2812642
-115937075 -115937323 2813756 2814011
-115910025 -115910146 2818095 2818198
-115909932 -115909986 2818205 2818262
-115909723 -115909789 2818703 2818768
```

I want to add a 5th column which is col4 minus col3.

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$4-$3}' | head

 2481311 41261568 2798880 2799128
 286939711 -115940021 2799541 2799827
 548939159 -115939706 2800137 2800685
 735939033 -115939106 2801113 2801186
 535938419 -115938978 2801191 2801726
 131937404 -115937535 2812511 2812642
 255937075 -115937323 2813756 2814011
 103910025 -115910146 2818095 2818198
 575909932 -115909986 2818205 2818262
 655909723 -115909789 2818703 2818768
```

It doesn't add the 5th column and instead does something weird to the first column.

Comment: Can you try `dos2unix` your file?

Comment: See also this excellent Q&A on SO [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @taliezin Yes! It works now. I forgot about that completely. The file does come from windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is ending in (Windows) `CR LF` instead of (Unix) `LF`.
The `CR` character moves the line to the start and then the value of the new calculated column is being printed over the first column.

Either use `dos2unix`, or filter the file with `tr -d '\r'` or simply use this:

```
awk 'NR>2 { gsub(/\r/,""); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$4-$3 } NR>12{exit}' file
```

remove the last `NR>12{exit}` to process the whole file.